# R memory issue with large polygon grid file

Tags: r

I have a  1 km by 1 km grid polygons for all of Ontario, Canada.
This file is roughly 1 GB with 1116965 rows and can downloaded here: https://www.ontario.ca/data/utm-universal-transverse-mercator-1-km-grid

When I read it into R using:

```
library(rgdal)
grid1 <- readOGR(dsn="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data", layer="1KM_GRID",encoding="utf-8")
```

It will print the console a few things and then my computer freezes, at a certain point it goes black and won't respond to any keyboard commands leaving me to force restart my computer.

I need this grid shapefile to later perform an spThin on it and I'd prefer to stay in R. My computer has 8GB of RAM and I'm running Windows 10 64-bit.

Is there a different package in R that deals with large spatial data such as ff for data.frames? Or are there settings I can change in R that will allow me to work with this data?

Comment: That's classic R behaviour for running out of RAM. Can you load the file with a computer with more memory and simplify it? Check out `rmapshaper::ms_simplify()`

Comment: @Phil Thanks, we do have a server computer that I may try next week. Oddly enough it opens in ArcMap okay. I don't know if I can simplify it as they're just grid shapes.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest it try your server, do your `spThin` analysis on that, and save out the results as an `RData` file to load onto other computers?